# Removing a list from a list of lists! PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x, list, sorting, min

```
a1=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],[3, 4] ,[3, 6], [4, 5]]
```

i want the output to be:

```
a1=[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

I've tried removing it with a for loop, but it throws an error index out of range

Comment: Can you show us the actual code that you tried? Also, are you just trying to remove the elements at index [2] and [5]? Or is there a criterion by which you want to filter the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pop()` if you want to remove by index (e.g. the fourth element):

```
In [1]: a1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],[3, 4] ,[3, 6], [4, 5]]

In [2]: a1.pop(4)
Out[2]: [3, 6]

In [3]: a1
Out[3]: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Or, you can remove by specifying the element:

```
In [4]: a1 = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4],[3, 4] ,[3, 6], [4, 5]]

In [5]: a1.remove([3, 6])

In [6]: a1
Out[6]: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple just use the pop function.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-pop/

For your case it would be :

`a1.pop(4)`

you can loop over the Pop() function to remove multiple ones.